# kantu firefox selenium - output a variable in field using type

Tags: kantu

I have a Kantu macro on firefox. I first declare a date variable to get current date - 2 days

```
{
      "Command": "storeEval",
      "Target": "var d= new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * -2); var m=((d.getMonth()+1)<10)?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1); d.getFullYear()+\"-\"+m+\"-\"+d.getDate();",
      "Value": "mydate"
    },
```

and then I try to type in my variable...

```
   {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "id=startDate",
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "type",
      "Target": "id=startDate",
      "Value": "{$mydate}"
    },
```

But the output I get in the field is the text {$mydate} when i should get something like '2018-09-11'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
{
  "Command": "type",
  "Target": "id=startDate",
  "Value": "${mydate}"
}
```